# Pushing random variables into array PHP

Tags: php

1. I declare an array called $stack
2. I make an if statement that checks if the button in my html body fired.
3. Once it is fired, I try to push a random value (via mt_rand) in my $stack array.
4. I print my array to see what values are in there.

With the variable y I try to increase the amount of times the for loop will run and thus there should be more values pushed into the array. This, however does not happen. Why doesn't his happen? I had the feeling that when I push the button, the page is refreshed and my $y variable is 0 once again. Is this correct?

I hope you can help me.

```
<html>
<head>
<?php

    $stack = array();
    if( isset($_POST['dobbelTrig'])){
        $y=0;
        $y++;

            for($x = 0; $x < $y; $x++){
                $newvalue = mt_rand(1,6);
                $stack[] = $newvalue;
            }

        print_r($stack);
    } 
?>
</head>
<body>

<p>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <input type="submit" value="dobbelen" name="dobbelTrig">
    </form>
 </p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why can't you set `$y=1`; instead of `$y=0; $y++;`? And if the value of $y is 1 obviously only one value will be added to the array

Comment: Your loop can only ever execute exactly once, given that you've set `$y` to `1` and you loop from `0` to `$y`.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. A `<p>` cannot contain a `<form>` so the form start tag implicitly closes the paragraph making the `</p>` an end tag without a matching start tag. Use [a validator](https://validator.nu).

Comment: PHP variables don't retain their state across requests. If you want to maintain state, you need either send the values to the client so they can send them back to you on a subsequent request, or store them some place like a database, cookies or in the session,

Answer (score 2):

First you set `$y` to `1`

> ```
> $y=0;
> $y++;
> ```

Then you loop between `0` and `$y`:

> ```
> for($x = 0; $x < $y; $x++){
> ```

So 0 is less than 1, so you add a value to the array.

Then 1 is not less than 1, so you stop.

At this point you have one value in the array.

---

When you click submit again, the program runs from the beginning. It creates a new array and puts one value in it.

If you want to persist data between form submissions then you need to store the results somewhere persistent (such as in a session, a database, or embedded in hidden input elements in the form).

Comment: That is exactly the reason why it didn't work. I've been trying to fix this for a while and well, The second part of your answer also solves my second question. I will look up how to retain data without a database (beginner here.). Thank you for your awesome input!

Answer (score 1):

Look here:

```
$y=0; // Y is 0
$y++; // Y is now 1
for($x = 0; $x < $y; $x++){ //So X is zero, when $x++ it is no longer < $y
```